# Purpose of pattern where object extends trait of the same name - object Live extends Live

Tags: scala, singleton, traits, zio

I am trying [ZIO](https://zio.dev).

I do not understand why `Live` is added as `Trait`, and then an `object` is provided, like:

```
object Live extends Live
```

This pattern is found in different places, for example `zio.console.Console`.

Is there a reason, or are there cases where this makes sense?

Comment: I do not use **ZIO** but what I understand for the source and the documentation is that those serve as a _"default"_ implementation of each fo the traits.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks, but `Live` is already an implementation. Another one is `Test` for example which does not extend from `Live`.

Comment: What do you mean with it is already an implementation, as a trait it is abstract, The object materializes the trait. I know the trait already have everything defined. I guess is just for leaving open the possibility to extending it latter on other parts. Or to have `Live` as a **type** _(thing an object would not do)_ or to allow some to write `val y = Live.x` and other one to write `object A extends Live { val y = x }`.

Comment: I think one rationale for this pattern is to provide easier and more incremental testability.  In **Testing Incrementally with ZIO Environment** the [Introduce a Database Module](http://degoes.net/articles/testable-zio#introduce-a-database-module) section shows a more descriptive example.  De Goes writes: *For maximum flexibility and convenience, we have defined both a trait that implements the database module, which can be mixed into other traits, and an object that extends the trait, which can be used standalone.*

Comment: @jq170727 thanks - with the answer of Krzysztof Atłasik I found the place where the `trait` is used `val myRuntime = 
  Runtime(
    new  DatabaseLive 
    with SocialLive 
    with EmailLive, PlatformLive)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you see in **ZIO** is the usage of a pattern called *Selfless Trait*.

To implement the selfless trait pattern you simply provide a companion object for a trait that itself mixes in the trait.

```
trait Greeting {
  def greet() { println("hi there") }
}

object Greeting extends Greeting
```

Then the user of the library has the choice to either mix-in `Greeting`:

```
object MixinExample extends Application with Greeting {
  greet()
}
```

or to import the members of the `Greeting` companion object, like this:

```
import Greeting._

object ImportExample extends Application {
  greet()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as an addition to *Krzysztof Atłasik* answer.

As mentioned in *jq170727* comment you find these two cases here:
[introduce-a-database-module](http://degoes.net/articles/testable-zio#introduce-a-database-module)

`Object`:

> In the worst case, if we are pressed for time and need to ship code
>   today, maybe we choose to provide the production database wherever we
>   call inviteFriends.

```
inviteFriends(userId).provide(DatabaseLive)
```

> In this case, instead of using the DefaultRuntime that ships with ZIO,
>   we can define our own Runtime, which provides the production database
>   module):

```
val myRuntime = Runtime(DatabaseLive, PlatformLive)
```

`Trait`:

When you have multiple *Runtimes*.

```
val myRuntime = 
  Runtime(
    new  DatabaseLive 
    with SocialLive 
    with EmailLive, PlatformLive)
```